# What could cause an Android activity to loop infinitely?

Tags: java, android, infinite-loop

I am writing a simple application to scan and record WiFi Access Points, there are three options; a single scan, 10 scans, or scan for a period of time.

When I enter my nWiFiScans activity it preforms the scans, records the file and STARTS THE ACTIVITY AGAIN!!!

WHY WOULD IT DO THIS???

## nWiFiScans.java

```
    public class nWiFiScans extends Activity 
    {
    //declarations
    public static String pntNameStr;
    public static int numScans;
    public static int scansMin;
    LinearLayout    layout1;
    ScrollView      scrollLayout;
    TextView        label1; 
    EditText        n1Text;
    EditText        n2Text;
    LayoutParams    params_layout1;

    WifiManager mainWifi = null;
    WifiReceiver receiverWifi;
    List<ScanResult> wifiList;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Intent intent;
    SimpleDateFormat time;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        scrollLayout = new ScrollView(this);
        scrollLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        //Create new layout in "this" activity
        params_layout1 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
        layout1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        layout1.setLayoutParams(params_layout1);
        //Create TextView in "this" activity
        label1 = new TextView(this);
        label1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        //Put some text in the TextView

        // Get the message from the intent
        intent = getIntent();
        pntNameStr = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_pntNameStr);
        numScans = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_numScans, 1);

        label1.setText(pntNameStr);


        //Place the TextView inside the Layout
        layout1.addView(label1);
        layout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        //scrollLayout.addView(label1);
        //layout1.addView(n1Text);
        //layout1.addView(n2Text);

        //By default the layout is set to HOR, so we change it to VERT orientation:

        // Display layout1 when the activity is created:
        setContentView(layout1);

        mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        checkIfWifiIsOn(mainWifi);

        receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        mainWifi.startScan();
        label1.setText("Starting Scan..."+String.valueOf(numScans));


    }

    public void checkIfWifiIsOn(WifiManager mainWifi)
    { 
        if (mainWifi.isWifiEnabled() == false)
        {  
            // If wifi disabled then enable it
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is disabled..making it enabled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            mainWifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        } 
        else {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is enabled... thats good...",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
    }

    public void generateNoteOnSD(String sFileName, String sBody)
    {
        File root = null;
        try
        {
            root = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("SurveyAppData"), "ScanResults");
            if (!root.exists()) 
            {
                root.mkdirs();
            }
            File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
            writer.append(sBody);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved" + "/n" +root.toURI(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IM MOTHERFUCKING DONE" ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Log.d("Scan Results",sb.toString());
            Intent i=new Intent(nWiFiScans.this, MainActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "!!! - Could NOT Saved" + "/n" +root.toURI(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }  


    public class WifiReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        // This method call when number of wifi connections changed
        long fisrtScanTS;
        private String FILENAME = pntNameStr;
        public FileOutputStream outputStream;

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) 
        {
            time = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
            int ScanTime = numScans;
            if(ScanTime==1 | ScanTime==10)
            {

                for (int scanNum = 1; scanNum<ScanTime+1; scanNum++)
                {
                    wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
                    for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++)
                    {               
                        sb.append(((wifiList.get(i)).BSSID + " " +  (wifiList.get(i)).level + " "  + (wifiList.get(i)).frequency + " "+ (wifiList.get(i)).timestamp + " "+ (wifiList.get(i)).SSID +" "+ time.format(new Date()) + "\n" ) );
                        fisrtScanTS = (wifiList.get(1)).timestamp;
                    } 

                    do
                    {
                        mainWifi.startScan();
                        wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
                        try{Thread.currentThread().sleep(200);}
                        catch(InterruptedException ie){
                            //If this thread was intrrupted by nother thread 
                        }
                    } while(fisrtScanTS == (wifiList.get(1)).timestamp);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Scan number " + scanNum ,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }else if (ScanTime!=0)
            {
                Calendar timeNow = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar timeEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
                timeEnd.set(timeNow.YEAR, timeNow.MONTH, timeNow.DAY_OF_MONTH, timeNow.HOUR, timeNow.MINUTE+numScans, timeNow.SECOND);
                while(!(timeNow.after(timeEnd))){
                    wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
                    for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++){               
                        sb.append(((wifiList.get(i)).BSSID + " " +  (wifiList.get(i)).level + " "  + (wifiList.get(i)).frequency + " "+ (wifiList.get(i)).timestamp + " "+ (wifiList.get(i)).SSID +" "+ time.format(new Date()) + "\n" ) );
                        fisrtScanTS = (wifiList.get(1)).timestamp;
                    }       
                    do {
                        mainWifi.startScan();
                        wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
                        try{Thread.currentThread().sleep(200);}
                        catch(InterruptedException ie){
                            //If this thread was intrrupted by nother thread 
                        }} while(fisrtScanTS == (wifiList.get(1)).timestamp);

                    timeNow = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), timeNow.getTime().toString() + " :: " + timeEnd.getTime().toString() ,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            generateNoteOnSD(FILENAME, sb.toString());
            FILENAME="x";
            ScanTime=0;
        }

    }   
}
```

## MainActivity.java

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    {
    LinearLayout mainLayout,leftLayout,rightLayout;
    EditText pointName;
    EditText scanTime;
    Button scan10, scan1, timedScan;
    TextView msg;
    LayoutParams paramsL,paramsR;
    static final String EXTRA_pntNameStr = "com.example.surveyappv2.pntNameStr";
    static final String EXTRA_scanTimeMin = "com.example.surveyappv2.scanTimeMin";
    static final String EXTRA_numScans = "com.example.surveyappv2.numScans";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        paramsL = new LayoutParams(500,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
        paramsR = new LayoutParams(500,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);

        leftLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        leftLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        leftLayout.setLayoutParams(paramsL);
        leftLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        leftLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

        rightLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        rightLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        rightLayout.setLayoutParams(paramsR);
        rightLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        rightLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        scanTime = new EditText(this);
        scanTime.setHint("Scan Duration (min)");
        scanTime.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);     
        pointName = new EditText(this);
        pointName.setHint("Enter Point Name");
        scan10 = new Button(this);
        scan1 = new Button(this);
        timedScan = new Button(this);
        msg = new TextView(this);

        scan10.setText("Do 10 Scans");
        scan1.setText("Do a Single Scan");
        timedScan.setText("Timed Scan");
        msg.setText("Alec Sucks");


        leftLayout.addView(pointName);
        leftLayout.addView(scanTime);
        rightLayout.addView(msg);
        rightLayout.addView(scan10);
        rightLayout.addView(scan1);
        rightLayout.addView(timedScan);

        mainLayout.addView(leftLayout);
        mainLayout.addView(rightLayout);
        mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        setContentView(mainLayout);
        setButtonClickListener();

    }

    private void setButtonClickListener()
    {
        scan10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                String message2 = "Button: \n" + scan10.getText();
                msg.setText(message2);
                startScan(mainLayout,10);

            }
        });

        scan1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                String message2 = "Button: \n" + scan1.toString();
                msg.setText(message2);
                startScan(mainLayout,1);
            }
        });

        timedScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                String message2 = "Button: \n" + timedScan.toString();
                msg.setText(message2);
                startScan(mainLayout,Integer.parseInt(scanTime.getText().toString()));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void startScan(View view, int numScans)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, nWiFiScans.class);
        String pntNameStr = pointName.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_pntNameStr, pntNameStr);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_numScans, numScans);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Starts which activity again: main one or wifi scan?

Comment: nWiFiScans is the activity being looped...

Comment: Main activity calls WIFIScans, and WiFiScans is the activity in the mystery loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran it, removed the file creation and the Intent(You only need to call finish();) and then it worked. Have you checked that it actually goes through File creation for you? Because mine got stuck there and then it jumps out of try so it can't reach the finish(); call, I also called `unregisterReceiver(receiverWifi);` before `finish();`

EDIT, File creation:

```
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); //returns sdcard directory
    File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/mydirectory");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, "filename");
```

Comment: while(1){THANK YOU}!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Your awesome!

Do you know whats the matter with the file writer?? im stuck :(

Comment: see Edit, also check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html).  always good to see if external storage is present and if not, save on internal, the different directories are listed on the link

Comment: Thanks for helping out a new android programmer!! i'll upvote when i have enough rep.